# How to deny some links which are similar to some that should be parsed by Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl an ecommerce store with some links that I want to deny and product pages, that I want to parse. An example of the data:

```
Parse:
domain.de/nike-Flasche-750-ml
domain.de/Nike-Tasche-schwarz-5
domain.de/Erima-Flasche-weiss-gruen-gelb-5
domain.de/Erima-Hose-rot-blau-gelb-weiss
domain.de/converse-4-Laufschuhe

Deny:
domain.de/service
domain.de/zahlung-versand
domain.de/Mein-Konto
domain.de/geschenkideen-fuer-sie
```

I've tried it with manually adding everything to one deny rule and then adding a general rule for all products `domain\.de\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}-)`
That spider kept on going over all categories, but never parsed a single item.

Then I've tried it within on expression:

```
domain\.de\/(?!zahlung-versand|service|Mein-Konto|geschenkideen-fuer-sie)([a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}-)
```

The pages of the negative lookahead are indeed not spidered. But still, no products are crawled and parsed.

If I remove the deny rules, products are parsed, as well as the URLs that should be on the deny list and then the parser breaks (since the page doesn't contain product data / product listing structure).

In regex things seem to be working though:

https://regex101.com/r/OtW6lb/1

Edit:

One obvious solution to get the spider still running would be, to simply do a return in case the spider runs into an error somewhere.
But I'd like to avoid crawling the pages in the first place (via regex if possible)

Edit 2:

My rules look like this in a JSON

```
"rules": [
    {
        "deny": ["\\.de\\/.*__"],
        "follow": false
    },
    {
        "allow": ["\\.de\\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}-)"],
        "follow": true,
        "use_content": true
    },
    {
        "allow": ["\\.de\\/(cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4)(?:_s[0-9]{1,})?$"],
        "follow": true
    }
],
```

And then, they are assigned in the spiders `__init__()` function:

```
for rule in self.MY_SETTINGS["rules"]:
allow_r = ()
if "allow" in rule.keys():
    allow_r = [a for a in rule["allow"]]

deny_r = ()
if "deny" in rule.keys():
    deny_r = [d for d in rule["deny"]]

restrict_xpaths_r = ()
if "restrict_xpaths" in rule.keys():
    restrict_xpaths_r = [rx for rx in rule["restrict_xpaths"]]

Sportygenspider.rules.append(Rule(
    LinkExtractor(
        allow=allow_r,
        deny=deny_r,
        restrict_xpaths=restrict_xpaths_r,
    ),
    follow=rule["follow"],
    callback='parse_item' if ("use_content" in rule.keys()) else None
))
```

With this rule order, `use_content` is never being called. The spider goes through all category pages though.
If I remove the deny rule for `__`, `use_content` is called on every page and I have to do `return` on some unfulfilled criteria from the about us page and similar.

Comment: Is there a difference in the positioning of the links in the html body? If so, you could use XPaths to identify the sections of html to search for links in. Let me know and I can write you an example solution if you like...

Comment: I thought about this as well via the `restrict_xpaths=()` parameter. It would probably work to exclude the header and footer of the page. But in this case, some URLs that I want to deny are nested inside the main navigation, just beside other URLs that should be parsed.

Comment: hmm difficult to say. Is the list of deny domains fixed? Or varies from page to page?

Comment: For this store, I have a fixed list that I'm building out - but there are some dynamic URLs as well coming from the filter navigation (I just discovered). They could be identified by `__`: `domain.de/geschenkideen-fuer-sie__schuhgroesse`

Comment: Did you re.compile your regex? It has to be a regular expression object. Not a string

Comment: Yes - if I dump the object, I can see the re.compile correctly.

Comment: Ah ok. Can you post some of your code. Would be easier to debug if I can see it

Comment: Spider is already 1000 lines long - but I've added the important parts, maybe you can see an obvious error in the logic there?

Comment: code you have posted isn't correctly indented. But it appears to be creating 3 spiders with different rules. Is that what you are intending?

Comment: 3 spiders? With `.rules.append()` those rules should only be added to the current spider?

Comment: Sorry 3 rules. I've written you an answer of what I think the solution is. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have initialised your spider with a list of rules for link extraction
- If more than one or your rules match a link, then only the [first matching rule will be used to parse that link](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider). This could explain why your callback **use_content** is not being called unless you remove the deny rule. Probably the deny rule is matching the same links as the allow rule. Therefore the links are only being processed by the deny rule and not the allow rule. Bear in mind that for LinkExtractor objects

  - [If you leave **allow** parameter empty the link extractor will match all links](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)
  - **deny** parameter can be used to blacklist links that shouldn't be matched
  - In your case the **deny** rule is matching all links that don't match the regex.
  - The **allow** rule is matching all links that do match the regex and then calling **use_content** on these. But it will not process links that have already been matched by the **deny** rule

It sounds to me as though you need to combine your **allow** and **deny** into one rule. 
For example changing your rules to this might work better with your existing code

```
"rules": [
{
    "deny": ["\\.de\\/.*__"],
    "allow": ["\\.de\\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}-)"],
    "use_content": true
    "follow": false
},
{
    "deny": ["\\.de\\/.*__"],
    "allow": ["\\.de\\/(cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4)(?:_s[0-9]{1,})?$"],
    "follow": true
}
],
```

Comment: Yes, you've been right - now I've got allow, deny and restrict_xpaths in the rules like you suggested. Plus: The ´rules.append(Rule ..´ has been indented wrong in my code as well - after the for, so only the last rule got assigned and now products got scraped.